# Testing whether a sequence of runs obeys a given distribution

Tags: probability, bayesian

Let $p ∼ B(α,β)$ and $X ∼ Bin(n,p)$. Given a sequence $x \in X$, how would I calculate the probability that x is indeed obeying the given distribution as opposed to some other distribution?

Comment: Please clarify your situation: is each $x$ obtained by drawing $p$ and then drawing from Bin$(n,p)$ or is the sequence obtained by drawing $p$ once and for all and then drawing an iid sequence from Bin$(n,p)$? And what does this have to do with the "runs" you refer to in the title?

Comment: The first situation.

Comment: Please don't delete and re-ask [essentially the same question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298595/wald-wolfowitz-with-a-beta-and-binomial-distribution). Instead, if the original is not quite what you want to ask, fix the original. By deleting you have removed a relevant point made at the original.

Comment: As I pointed out previously --- a test can't tell you that your data are from any particular distribution.  i.e. you **cannot** say that X "is indeed obeying the given distribution". A test may sometimes tell you that it isn't, but in practice there are always going to be other alternatives that also fit. You will need to modify your aim, at least somewhat, to something that can be achieved.